# Not Qualified to work on this HIT in Sandbox Envrionment

Tags: mechanicalturk

I am trying to accept a HIT as a worker from sandbox but every time it shows following message.

"Your request for the Qualification "Categorization Masters" has been submitted to Requester Amazon Mechanical Turk"

Can anybody say what I am missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sandbox works just like the live site, as in you (as a worker) have to be meet the qualifications in order to accept a HIT. This means if you're trying to complete your own HIT in the sandbox just to try it out, you have two options:

1. Remove the QualificationRequirements from the HIT so you can complete it.
2. Obtain the necessary qualifications in the sandbox in order to satisfy the requirements.

Option 1 is easy (and is what you should do). Option 2 is difficult, or maybe impossible.

Comment: For option-1, how to remove QualificationRequirements. I never create any qualification, still why it is needed.

Comment: Whether you knew it, or not, you have a masters qualification requirement. You probably used the categorization project template, which requires it.